# Mic device not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: alsa, microphone, multimedia, pavucontrol

I already installed pavucontrol and checked alsamixer for further verification, but I don't see an end to my problem.
This is my 
[Alsa Info](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=377ea2cb7de1eb5d20230b4dc5a144616bb29a6d)

I already reinstalled alsa-pulseaudio, and force-realod.

Did

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*

pulseaudio -k
```

did

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

But none of the above solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open `pulse audio` gui with `pulseaudio` in your terminal (or search for  `pulseaudio`)

As you can see in the following screenshot, you need to select `Input Devices` or `Dispositivos de Entrada`, choose the correct microphone (the one plugged in) and unmute it with the highlighted button.

[image]

Then you will see that the microphone picking up the sound as in the below picture

[image]

Then [select recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFoCx.png) and configure your mic for the desired application. Every application (for ex. skype, spotify etc..) can have a different configuration and have different audio settings. You could mute skype, but unmute a different application.

Comment: nnss@nnss-laptop:~$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.

Comment: The thing ist that in pavucontrol shows my microphone as unplugged, even though I have estero headphone option selected.

Comment: @NicollasSoares could you post a picture of the screen, to better understand what you are talking about. You can configure your mic in `PulseAudio` for every application you are using.. so be sure to start the application and select the correct input in `PulseAudio` .. For example show us a screen with pulse audio and skype open

Comment: Here is what I got 
https://imgur.com/a/AdTVXQB

Comment: @NicollasSoares I updated my answer with the solution based on your scenario. Thanks!

Comment: When trying to do `pulseaudio` on the Terminal I get this
`E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() falhou.`
In the link below shows that my microphone is (unplugged), eve though I have headphones.
https://imgur.com/a/Ucn7tPV

Comment: @NicollasSoares you need to select the `plugged in` microphone and unmute it.

Comment: @NicollasSoares if you don't have any microphone showing as plugged in, you need to give us information about your hardware (microphone and computer) as [there is a bug in alsa audio](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1596381) and you may have to install some packages